# Pixel level manipulation windows

Tags: windows, graphics, sdl, pixel

I've been using SDL to render graphics in C. I know there are several options to create graphics at the pixel level on Windows, including SDL and OpenGL. But how do these programs do it? Fine, I can use SDL. But I'd like to know what SDL is doing so I don't feel like an ignorant fool. Am I the only one slightly frustrated by the opaque layer of frosting on modern computers?

A short explanation as to how this is done on other operating systems would also be interesting, but I am most concerned with Windows.

Edit: Since this question seems to be somehow unclear, this is precisely what I want:
I would like to know how pixel level graphics manipulations (drawing on the screen pixel by pixel) works on Windows. What do libraries like SDL do with the operating system to allow this to happen. I can manipulate the screen pixel by pixel using SDL, so what magic happens in SDL to let me do this?

Comment: When you ask "these programs do it", what are "these programs" and what is the "it" that they do?

Comment: SDL and OpenGL rendering graphics. Obviously they talk to the OS in some way. I want to know what they're saying.

Comment: What is your specific problem with which you are struggling? Pure curiosity questions like »How does *X* work?« are rarely on topic.

Comment: Yeah "how does X work". Don't tell me Stack Overflow has a vendetta against questions for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: There's no vendetta against questions for the sake of curiosity, but your question is too broad and too vague. "Rendering Graphics" encompasses everything from drawing a single point to the screen to BRDFs, volumetric shadows, convolutions, color corrections, distortions, etc. Please be more specific about what you want to know. Also, the specific answer may be unknowable to those without source to the OS or drivers in some cases. (For example, OpenGL will eventually call a vendor's driver to run code on the specific hardware in your machine.)

Comment: I think I was pretty clear. I want to see how pixel level manipulation works. Unless I am much mistaken, which I may be, this is handled at an OS level, not a hardware level, which would make the answer perfectly knowable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has many graphics APIs.  Some are layers built on top of others (e.g., GDI+ on top of GDI), and others are completely independent stacks (like the Direct3D family).

In an API like GDI, there are functions like [SetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which let you change the value of a single pixel on the screen (or within a region of the screen that you have access to).  But using SetPixel to setting lots of pixels is generally slow.

If you were to build a photorealistic renderer, like a ray tracer, then you'd probably build up a bitmap in memory (pixel by pixel), and use an API like [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that sends the entire bitmap to the screen at once.  This is much faster.

But it still may not be fast enough for rendering something like video.  Moving all that data from system memory to the video card memory takes time.  For video, it's common to use a graphics stack that's closer to the low-level graphics drivers and hardware.  If the graphics card can do the video decompression directly, then sending the compressed video stream to the card will be much more efficient than sending the decompressed data from system memory to the video card--and that's often the limiting factor.

But conceptually, it's the same thing:  you're manipulating a bitmap (or texture or surface or raster or ...), but that bitmap lives in graphics memory, and you're issuing commands to the GPU to set the pixels the way you want, and then to display that bitmap at some portion of the screen (often with some sort of transformation).

Modern graphics processors actually run little programs--called shaders--that can (among other things) do calculations to determine the pixel values.  The GPUs are optimized to do these types of calculations and can do many of them in parallel.  But ultimately, it boils down to getting the pixel values into some sort of bitmap in video memory.

Comment: And when you tell a graphics card to render a video, draw some polygons, do some pixel shading, or something else, does the graphics card render this directly to video memory, or does the OS take all of the bits and pieces of pictures, paste the image in one window over another window, and then stick all of this in video memory?

Comment: @BigEndian: A modern OS will arrange for the graphics card to render directly to video memory whenever feasible.  Moving the data across the graphics bus to system memory and then back again to video memory would be prohibitively expensive.  Graphics buses are pretty fast nowadays, but they can still easily become a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks :)
Now I'm going to look at BitBlt!